# How to print rows greater than N in at least X number of columns?

Tags: r

For example, how can I print rows greater than 300 in at least 2 columns?

The following code print rows greater than 300

```
mtcars[apply(mtcars[, -1], MARGIN = 1, function(x) any(x > 300)), ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple ways come to mind:

```
mtcars[apply(mtcars, 1, FUN = function(x) sum(x > 300) >= 2),]
```

or

```
mtcars[rowSums(mtcars > 300) >= 2,]
```

Which both return

```
#               mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
# Maserati Bora  15   8  301 335 3.54 3.57 14.6  0  1    5    8
```

Comment: I couldn't get the logic behind the `sum(x>300)>=2` though.

Comment: `x > 300` returns a logical vector with TRUE/FALSE for each value in the row. Summing up these logical values returns the number of values in each row that are > 300